# Detect Javascript injection in network traffic

Tags: javascript, security, vpn, privacy, javascript-injection

This is my first question here in stackoverflow, so pardon me if I am missing something!

I'm working on a project related to VPN security. They main goal of the project is to detect if a VPN client is introducing some sort of malware ( spyware included ) in my activity. They may do so in orther to get some proffit out of their VPN, for not many people offer good things for free!

I know Javascript Injection for tracking porposes is a thing. What I want to know is the following:

Is there any way to find if Javascript has been injected by analyzing network traffic? Let's say I don't trust that my VPN is not tracking me by Javascript injection. Could I know by analyzing the traffic on a router?

Thanks in advance, hope I have made myself clear!

Comment: Put a server out there that has known output.  Run it through your VPN, and compare what you get with the known output.

Comment: Assuming you also have access to the same resources without using the VPN, you could simply use `curl`/`wget` and `diff` to compare the results.

Comment: Also, source from a reputable vendor.

Comment: You may get better answers at https://security.stackexchange.com/